# Обособление приложений в середине предложения (тире)

Tags: приложение, сложное-предложение

Есть предложение:

*...но он продолжал заниматься своим делом – лечить людей – хотя ему было около шестидесяти лет.*

Нужно ли ставить запятую после второго тире (так как это сложное предложение)?
То есть написать так: *...но он продолжал заниматься своим делом – лечить людей –, хотя ему было около шестидесяти лет.*

Answer (score 3):

«...но он продолжал заниматься своим делом – лечить людей, хотя ему было около шестидесяти лет.»

*Лечить людей* — несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова а именно, отделяется посредством тире. В середине предложения такое несогласованное определение выделяется с двух сторон с помощью тире. Если по условиям контекста после определения должна стоять запятая, то второе тире обычно опускается:

> Так как оставался один выбор — потерять армию и Москву или одну
>   Москву, то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы настаиваете, что "лечить людей" — уточнение, требующее по авторскому пониманию именно парного тире, то опускать ни второе тире, ни запятую, естественно, нельзя.

Но для таких случаев есть правило, что запятая непосредственно после тире (любого, парного или непарного) не ставится, только перед ним.

Поэтому:
***...но он продолжал заниматься своим делом – лечить людей, – хотя ему было около шестидесяти лет.***

Кому-то на первый взгляд может показаться непривычным, поскольку нарушается структура вложенности, ибо запятая попадает внутрь фрагмента, ограниченного парным тире, но такой подход оправдан, такая пунктуация не сказывается на восприятии смысла, но сохраняет естественную и привычную последовательность знаков.

Это не значит, что предлагаемый вариант без второго тире вовсе неправилен.

Просто тогда надо по-другому трактовать грамматику (см. doom), это тоже вполне оправдано.

Comment: ещё две опечатки

Comment: @shampar Спасибо. Только две? Не так много для меня в нынешнем состоянии. Я четыре исправил ))).

Comment: @shampar Да, я  помимо всегдашней общей невнимательности стал испытывать еще и определенные трудности при работе с текстом, а опыта борьбы с ними, трудностями, у меня нет. ))) Так что не стесняйтесь, правьте, если уверены.